# Retrieving SQLAlchemy query objects through declaritive_base class methods

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't help but think that the number of keystrokes required to do a query in SQLAlchemy is a little on the high side.

```
DBSession.query(User).filter(...).first()
```

Is there anything wrong with doing something like this?

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

class BaseWithDBSession(object):
    def delete(self):
        DBSession.delete(self)

    @classmethod
    def query(cls):
        return DBSession.query(cls)


Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseWithDBSession)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

user = User.query().filter(User.id==1).one()
user.delete()
```

This approach seems a lot neater to me, and it also means I don't have to import DBSession between code files.  The downside is that all of my classes are tied to a particular session, but I can't think of any situation in which I would want anything different.  I'm trying to think of reasons why I haven't seen this approach before (apart from my inexperience)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways of doing this sort of thing - see Mike Bayer's tongue-in-cheek post about [Magic, a "new" ORM](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/05/17/magic-a-new-orm/). SQLAlchemy postions itself as a toolkit rather than a framework, so that it can be used in different ways according to the needs of different scenarios. For example, there will be scenarios when a single session is not enough.

There are also third-party declarative layers on top of SQLAlchemy - e.g. [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/). It offers a slightly different way of doing things.

Comment: Mike Bayer's quote, "SQLAlchemy isn't a framework ... it's a toolkit", seems to sum up my conceptual issues, and Elixir does exactly what I specified above.  Thanks.